# Is this naive algorithm for calculating Minimum Bounding Circle correct?

Tags: algorithm

**I know there are tons of algorithms for calculating smallest enclosing circle (SEC)on the web.But I wonder why a simple algorithm won't work for it.**

Here is my idea:  I have a set of points and I think I can calculate their smallest enclosing circle (SEC) using the following approach:

1. calculate the center of all points and consider it as the center of
       the SEC (cPoint)
2. calculate the distance between every point in the
       set and cPoint. Consider the largest distance as the radius of SEC

Will this work?

Comment: How will you calculate the center of all points? If you're just taking the average of all x and y values, I don't think it will work. Consider the points (-10,0), (10,0), and (0, 9). The average of the three will be around (5,0), but the true center of the smallest circle should be the origin.

Comment: How do you calculate the "center"? And what center (center of mass, center of edge half lines...)?

Comment: Consider this, consider an X-axis from -10 to +10. Put 1 point at -10, a second point at +10, then put a billion points at -9. How do you determine the correct center for this? Any seemingly impossible or hard task can be "simplified" if you just rewrite it as a couple of steps, one of which is just another impossible/hard problem. But you haven't really accomplished anything.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work unless you have an unusual definition for the'center of all points'. For example if the center is chosen as the average of the points it fails with the set{(0,0),(0,1),(0,1)} as the center would be (0,2/3) and the bounding circle would have radius 2/3, whereas the correct bounding circle is centered on (0,1/2) with radius 1/2.

You can choose an appropriate definition for 'center of all points' for which your method would work, but that definition would be algorithmically equivalent to the 'tons of algorithms' you know about.

Answer (score 1):

This procedure will indeed give you an enclosing circle, but not always the smallest possible.

Just a counterexample:

Consider the triangle PQR forming an obtuse angle at Q. The circle having PR as a diameter is an enclosing circle. Consider any center of the triangle (centroid, orthocenter...); not being aligned with PR, it will be at a distance from either P or R larger than the radius, and will require a larger circle.

This doesn't mean that you procedure should be dropped in any case, it can produce reasonably tight results.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a cluster of arbitrarily many points, and one lone point that is far away, you can make the "center" inside the cluster without helping to find a circle that encloses the outlying point.

Of course there is a center point for the smallest enclosing circle, but this kind of argument shows that you aren't likely to find it in under O(n) time, because every point must be considered.